# How to run Jruby 1.6.6 on Aptana Studio 3.0.8 *ON WINDOWS*

Tags: windows, jruby, aptana, aptana3

I *have* read the launching Jruby from Aptana Studio 3 on Windows XP thread (to be fair, I am on windows 7) and created the wrapper script ruby.bat (*@C:\jruby-1.6.6\bin\jruby %** - MY particular path)

Tried naming it "just" ruby, ruby.sh whatever, but Aptana wont find it. From any windows shell (cmd) it works without a hitch.

Also tried copying the JRuby.exe to Ruby.exe. That still won't work. Linking ruby.exe to jruby.exe with the mklink command still wont work.

Looked around the internet, but all I found are dead ends.

Any fix to this? Can't be THAT rare a setup, THAT difficult, or can it?

Answer (score 0):

I did that by a simple trick...
I created a c++ file ruby.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    string cmd = "jruby.exe" ;
    for (int i = 1 ; i < argc ; ++i)
        cmd.append( " " ).append( argv[i] ) ;
    return system( cmd.c_str() ) ;
}
```

Compiled as ruby.exe and moved to C:\jruby-1.6.6\bin.
It works...